# Why does this simple equation involving an integral hold?

Tags: integration, transformation

Within an exercise, I was wondering about this step of solving an equation:

\begin{align}
\int_0^s \frac{\dot{z}(t)}{f(z(t))} \text{d}t = s \\
\Leftrightarrow \int_{z(0)}^{z(s)} \frac{1}{f(z(t))} \text{d}t = s
\end{align}

It seems easy, but Im confused about why this holds; Im thinking something to do with coordinate transformation or Jacobian determinate, but I better ask y'all. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely they are using the substitution $u=z(t)$, then as $t$ varies from $0$ to $s$, $u$ will vary from $z(0)$ to $z(s)$. But the integral will be given by $$\int_{z(0)}^{z(s)} \frac{1}{f(u)} \, du.$$

Comment: @AnuragA good catch! Thanks for your hint, I hadn't thought of substitution. I think it might work though for my purposes. If you formulate an answer, I'll be happy to give you credit. Cheers